# How to convert QVector<QString> to QVector<double>

Tags: qt, qtableview, qcustomplot

`QCustomPlot` takes a `QVector<double>` variable.
My `QTableView` contains data as `QVector<QString>`, which is want to plot.

1. I am looking for a way to do the conversion.
2. What is the best way to plot the values in QtableView?

Comment: `QString::toDouble()` function might help.

Answer (score 1):

UPDATED

As the comment says, you need a conversion function something like this:

```
QVector< double > toFloatVector( const QVector< QString >& aVector )
{
    QVector< double > vector;
    for ( const auto& item : aVector )
    {
        bool ok = true;
        const double value = item.toDouble( &ok );
        if ( ok )
        {
            vector << value;
        }
        // ... do something if the conversion failes.
    }
    return vector;
}
```

Comment: You have to return the `vector` after the for loop is done and not after the first iteration.

Comment: Sorry, I made a huge mistake, I fix it.